# IIS8 and ARR 3.0 using different SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, iis-8, arr

We would like to use our expensive company named SSL certificate on the ARR load balance server and rewrite URLs to the content (web)servers which will use a general wildcard SSL certificates. Is this possible or is it restricted to using the same SSL certificates in the server farm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is very possible and how I have done it in the past.

The content servers share the same wildcard certificate (not visible to public) while the ARR servers have a certificate that is viewed by the public.